# How can I trigger a "change" function on document ready?

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I have a "change" function and I want to trigger it on pageload.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".myfunc").trigger("change");

$(document).off("change", ".myfunc").on("change", ".myfunc", function (event) {
    alert("ok");
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting now the alert "ok" but nothing happens...

Comment: You have to trigger **after** you set up the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering the event first, and binding it afterwards. Move the `trigger` call to below the `on` call so that the event binding happens first:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).off("change", ".myfunc").on("change", ".myfunc", function(event) {
    alert("ok");
  });
  
  $(".myfunc").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myfunc">test</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok, I understand